# Correct way to have statistics from child entities

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, performance, entity-framework

Please help me find a way to make this efficient

The program has this entities:
Projects 1-N Modules
Modules 1-N Submodules .
Submodules 1-N Segments .
each segment has different status (default / completed) and wordcount

The wordcount is made when the segments are inserted into the database and stored in a column.

**Views.
Project List**
There should be less than 100 projects so for that im listing all of them without include's .

**Module List** (with parameter of 1 projectId) should have a column with words completed/total and rows completed/ total

**Submodule List** (with parameter of 1 moduleId) should have a column with words completed/total and rows completed/ total

Assume i would have around 50k rows (segments ) per module . so perfomance is a must.

*Option 1:*
IQueryable Childs.Count() of some sort
*Option 2:*
Add Stats columns to tables in database with CRON jobs to update them
or to have a stored proccedure / triggers in mysql .
*Option 3?:* Creating 2 views in mysql? have never done them but maybe they are right for the job?
***Options suggested: None yet***

Have never worked with such big datasets before and performance is a must. 
Please advice

Comment: What is your specific question? Please show the code that's not working.

Comment: Its not that its not working , i dont know whats the correct way to have this sort of statistics of children entities calculated. They are big tables and dont want to set the server on fire each time i load a view. The specific Question would be: How to efficiently display Completed words / Total words in the views

Comment: Why not try the 3 options and measure the difference? Typically a view on the database side is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = _context.Submodules.Where(t => t.Id == id)
                    .Select(e => new Submodules{
                        Id = e.Id,
                        Name = e.Name,
                        Status = e.Status,
                        Token = e.Token,
                        ModuleId = e.ModuleId,
                        Gender = e.Gender,
                        TotalRows = e.TotalRows,
                        TotalWords = e.TotalWords,
                        CompletedWords = e.Segments.Where(a => a.Status == Abr.Recorded).Sum(y=> y.Wordcount),
                        CompletedRows = e.Segments.Where(a => a.Status == Abr.Recorded).Count()
                    }).ToList();
```